# How to create an array and save them into database?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, foreach

Based on the code below, how would I create an array and then save the arrays to the database?

```
<?php
$all_userid = '';
if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
    foreach($_POST['userid'] as $userid) {
        // Add filtering here
        $all_userid .= $userid;
    }
}
echo $all_userid;
?>
```

Output from echo;

```
003210032100321
```

Comment: This is so basic. You need to google on how to create arrays.

Comment: What is your approach to save it into database?

Comment: echo $all_statuses; not echo($all_userid);

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp I guess this could help you

Comment: @helle No, you should really NOT use w3schools as a source of information. w3schools is known to provide outdated, and often even wrong, information. If you want proper tutorials, look for sites with a better reputation. w3schools is considered to be quite bad.

Comment: When inserting into the database, you should probably use mysqli since mysql is deprecated and I see lots of people still using mysql. Just a tip.

Comment: @Tularis: It seems accurate for me when it's about deep basics.

Answer (score 0):

you can implode them with an `-` or `/` or `_` and save them.Like

```
$i = 0;
$cnt = count($_POST['status']);
foreach($_POST['status'] as $status) {
    // Add filtering here
    $all_statuses .= $status;
    if($i++ < $cnt) {
        $all_statuses .= '_';
    }
}
echo $all_statuses;
```

Will gives you like

```
id1_id2_id3_id4....
```

And while retriving you simply explode them with the imploded string,you will get all the result in form of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode http://www.php.net/json_encode

```
$string = json_encode($array);
```

Then when retriving it from database, use json_decode http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$all_statuses = '';
if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    foreach($_POST['status'] as $status) {
        // Add filtering here
        $all_statuses .= $status;
    }
}
echo($all_statuses);
```

To Save in database serialize this array

```
serialize($all_statuses)
?>
```